How to test python logging handler TimedRotatingFileHandler
I want to use TimedRotatingFileHandler for rotating the log files at some specific time, let's say 23:00
Here is the config that I'm using:

LOGGING = {
    "version": 1,
    "disable_existing_loggers": True,
    "formatters": {
        "f_file_text": {
            "class": "logging.Formatter",
            "datefmt": "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S",
            "format": "[%(asctime)s] [%(levelname)-7s] [%(name)-15s] %(message)s",
        },
    },
    "handlers": {
        "h_file_text": {
            "class": "logging.handlers.TimedRotatingFileHandler",
            "filename": BASE_DIR.joinpath("logs/rm.txt.log"),
            "when": "D",
            "interval": 1,
            "atTime": datetime.time(23, 0),
            "backupCount": 7,
            "formatter": "f_file_text",
        },
    },
    "loggers": {
        "test": {
            "handlers": ["h_file_text"],
            "propagate": False,
        }
    },
}

def configure_logging() -> None:
    logging.config.dictConfig(LOGGING)

So i wrote a simple test using freezegun library
def test():
    configure_logging()

    test_logger = logging.getLogger("test")

    initial_datetime = datetime(year=2023, month=1, day=1, hour=20, minute=0, second=0)
    other_datetime = datetime(year=2023, month=1, day=2, hour=20, minute=0, second=0)
    with freeze_time(initial_datetime) as frozen_datetime:
        test_logger.error("Log message before")
        frozen_datetime.move_to(other_datetime)
        test_logger.error("Log message after")

I just can't get it work, it keeps writing both lines into the same file.
BUT
if I set the logging config to:
...
"when": "S",
"interval": 1,
...

and then run the test like this:
...
test_logger.error("Log message before")
time.sleep(2)
test_logger.error("Log message after")
...

then everything works fine.
How can I test my logging configuration using larger time intervals by patching current time and checking log file creation that happens every day?

do you write time in log? Do you see time 23:00 ? Maybe freezegun doesn't with logging. maybe you should test it with different atTime to test it in current moment instead of waiting to 23:00
